# Android. What is android:popupPromptView?

Tags: android, spinner

I develop for android. My IDE is Eclipse. I've been working with spinners recently. When making spinner layout, eclipse suggested my such an attribute: android:popupPromptView, eclipse built-in documentation says the following about it:

```
Reference to a layout to use for displaying a prompt in the 
 dropdown for spinnerMode="dropdown". [reference]
```

However, once I use it, eclipse tells me the following:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:popupPromptView'.
```

Then I go to android official docs, spinner page, where I see no `android:popupPromptView` at all... How can that be possible? Does this attribute exist? If yes, how to get rid of mistakes once I use it?

Comment: I too have experienced this and would like to know whats going on.

Answer (score -1):

You can declera spinner in simple way

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_adit_region"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`<item name="android:popupPromptView">@android:layout/simple_dropdown_hint</item>` is used for spinner customisation